# Qt cross-compilation for BeagleBoard-xM issue (ARM8)

Tags: qt, arm, ubuntu-12.04, cross-compiling, beagleboard

I have a big problem with Qt libraries cross-compilation. My objective is to develop some Qt-apps for my BeagleBoard-xM on my host machine running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I found some nice tutorials, e.g.:

http://treyweaver.blogspot.com/2010/10/setting-up-qt-development-environment.html

but the toolchain, which Trey used (angstrom-2010.4-test-20100422-i686-linux-armv7a-linux-gnueabi-toolchain-qte-4.6.2), it just disappeared, so I tried some toolchains from Ubuntu repository (gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi, gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf). And now, when I run 'configure' (with all parameters from Trey's tutorial) and then try to run 'make', it breaks with this error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/../lib/crt1.o:
In function `_start': (.text+0x30): undefined reference to `main' collect2: 
ld returned 1 exit status make[1]: *** [../../lib/libQtCoreE.so.4.8.5] Error 1
```

I found somewhere, that it might be some linking issue, but I have completely no idea, what to do with that...

Maybe someone has similar problem and could give me some advice?

Regards
jerzu

Comment: Are you still using the same versions of downloads as in the referenced page? Regardless, for Ubuntu 12.04 you must use the *-gnueabihf toolchain - forget about the *-gnueabi one.

Comment: You mean Qt-libraries version or toolchain version? I downloaded Qt 4.8.5 which is, I think, the last version that is suitable to mentioned tutorial (the Author recommend to download the last stable version and I've tried 5.0 and higher, but they look completely different than previous - 4.x.x). If we're talking about toolchains, I've used both - gnueabi and gnueabihf. I even have installed Ubuntu 10.04 on my PC to check, if my problem is caused by OS-version (10.04 was in the tutorial above), but it's not...

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, did you solve it?

Comment: Hi, try to read this:

[link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/beagleboard/beagleboard-xm/3vQ2rN7udIo)

Hope it will be helpful... Please let us know if you solve it that way too, I'm a little confused if it is really a good way.